# How to use Token auth in Postman?

Tags: postman

I'm trying to connect to a REST API using an authorization token.  It works in `curl` like this:

```
curl https://csp.infoblox.com/api/ddi/v1/dhcp/fixed_address \
--header "Authorization: Token $TOKEN
```

I can't figure out how to make [Postman](https://www.postman.com) use this same type of authorization.  The closest option I see is Bearer Token, which fails with 401 error and looks like this:

```
curl --location 'https://csp.infoblox.com/api/ddi/v1/dhcp/fixed_address' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer xxxx'
```

So apparently I'm trying to use some other type of token, not bearer.  Is there a name for this type of token?

I know I could enter this Authorization header in each request, but that's not safe and I'd like to inherit from the parent collection.